# Can external PHP running from another site access mysql running on an ASP.net hosted site?

Tags: php, mysql, asp.net, mysqli, database-connection

My issue is that my external MYSQL connection is getting denied access, however connecting to the internal mysql server on the PHP supported host works perfect.

The error:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'user_name'@'10.246.64.218' (using password: YES)

The code:

```
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "user_name";
 $password = "password";
 $database = "db_com_db";

// Create connection 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Since the error message is a bit vague my best guess is that it has something to do with the fact that it is external and possibly the fact that it is connecting to an asp.net suite.

**So can external PHP running from another site access mysql running on an ASP.net hosted site?**

I am not looking for a unnecessary difficult yes, more an quick yes or no because of something.

Comment: Sure, if mysql is configured to accept remote connections.

Comment: And I'm guessing that is not the default scenario? So I would then have to change it to accept remote connections? Sorry for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: The default scenario is that mysql is binded to only accept local connections. Read this http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: A lot of hosting accounts have remote connections disabled by default for databases. It would be best to check the hosting configuration tools, and/or consult hosting technical support. Whether MySQL is hosted on Windows or Linux, shouldn't make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

Combination of username, host, and password are not allowed to connect to the server.

Give permission to this external remote PHP task in from your MySQL instance , verify the permission - reload grants - and try again.

Also check with the hosting if they disable any remote connection .